# How to plot two estimates with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, compare

What is the most efficient ggplot code for this?
[image: 1]

In my dataset, I calculated two estimates that I want to compare As shown in the picture. Is there some example code? The estimates are calculated by lme()

Comment: Daniel, welcome to this forum. This is more about specific coding problems and without a minimum effort from your side difficult to really help you. I suggest have a thorough read of https://ggplot2-book.org and for your specific question https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/ggplot-error-bars/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, please take a look at the solution below. If it solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept, this would be very helpful to others. Otherwise, feel free to use the comments to ask for clarification/further information/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to `nlme::lme`, then here is a minimal example using the Orthodont-dataset, assuming you are interested in the fixed effect-parts (otherwise this can be ajusted accordingly)

```r
library(nlme)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)


fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont, subset = Sex == "Female")
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont, subset = Sex == "Male")

est1 <- tidy(fm1) %>% filter(effect == "fixed")
est2 <- tidy(fm2) %>% filter(effect == "fixed")

ggplot() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(estimate, term, xmin = estimate - std.error, xmax = estimate + std.error ),
                  data = est1, position = position_nudge(y = 0.1), color = "red") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(estimate, term, xmin = estimate - std.error, xmax = estimate + std.error ),
                  data = est2, position = position_nudge(y = -0.1), color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>